# Splitting tasks in gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Right now I have multiple gulpfiles. Everytime I get to work I need to run mulptiple "gulp --gulpfile path/to/another-gulpfile.js". Can I run it with one command? I tried "gulp --gulpfile gulpfile1.js gulpfile2.js gulpfile3.js", but it didn't work.

EDIT:

```
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "gulp --gulpfile bin/gulp-tasks/config.js && gulp --gulpfile bin/gulp-tasks/deploy.js"
  }
```

I tried running multiple gulp instances using npm scripts, but it looks like only watchers from first specified gulpfile are working. Simple console.logging showed, that second gulpfile was not even started. They do work perfectly when launched separately.

Comment: Why would you use multiple gulpfiles?

Answer (score 1):

one way you can try put your gulp command in npm package.json

```
scripts: {
  gulp: gulp --gulpfile path/to/gulpfile1.js && gulp --gulpfile path/to/gulpfile2.js
}
```

then you can run one command `npm run gulp`;

the other way you can refer to this post for more details
http://macr.ae/article/splitting-gulpfile-multiple-files.html

Comment: Thanks, it does the trick. I wonder if there is a way within gulp functionality alone? Well, I use npm anyway, so don't know if it matters a lot.

Comment: False alarm. I noticed that only watchers from first specified gulpfile are working. Modified post for more info.